# xml editing is it possible somehow?

Tags: xml, csv, awk, edit, gawk

I'm not sure that the following task can be done. I have already done the first part of it so I put here some codes that I'd like to work with further. This question might be a bit long, sorry for that. I'd like to edit an xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
        <label id="0" color="80FF80">BadReg</label>
        <label id="1" color="FFFF40">GoodReg</label>
        <label id="2" color="8000FF">Bluffer</label>
        <label id="3" color="10FF10">Fish</label>
        <label id="4" color="1080FF">Loose</label>
        <label id="5" color="30DBFF">Semi-Loose</label>
        <label id="6" color="0000FF">Nit</label>
        <label id="7" color="FF9F48">Tight</label>
        <label id="8" color="C0C0C0">Undefined</label>
    </labels>
    <note player="00aquitis00" label="7" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="01 LUGAR" label="8" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="07 Star 07" label="4" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="109185" label="6" update="1429834930">Some notes are here</note>
    <note player="1111167" label="8" update="1429834930">And some there...</note>
</notes>
```

I'd like to edit certain player's id's and their label numbers in the *.xml file above. First I have a players.txt and a ReportExport.csv file and they look like this, CSV:

```
"","Player","VPIP","PFR","Hands","Players"
"2532|100|""Seikei""&5RS","""Seikei""&5RS","20.45","12.50","88","5.65"
"4265|100|#23Mattingly","#23Mattingly","41.94","25.81","33","5.55"
"2748|100|#PachnacyBak","#PachnacyBak","11.54","10.00","52","5.44"
"6|100|eagle189","eagle189","20.60","13.60","73,561","5.55"
```

TXT:

```
player1         badreg
player2         badreg
player3         bluffer
player4         bluffer
```

In the first step I get the data (what I want to work with) from the *.txt and the *.csv file. AWK code:

```
BEGIN   {
                update = 1429834930 }

FILENAME == "players.txt"   {

                FS = "\t\t"

                playertype = $2;

                if (playertype == "badreg") {badregs[$1]++};
                if (playertype == "bluffer") {bluffers[$1]++};
                if (playertype == "fish") {fishes[$1]++};
                if (playertype == "goodreg") {goodregs[$1]++};
                next }

(FILENAME == "ReportExport.csv") && (FNR != 1)  {

                FS = "\",\""

                name = $2;
                vpip = $3;
                pfr = $4;
                hands = $5;
                avgp = substr($6, 1, (length($6)-1));

                if (name == "") {name = "Name"}

                gsub(/&/, "\\&amp;", name)
                gsub(/</, "\\&lt;", name)
                gsub(/>/, "\\&gt;", name)
                gsub(/\"\"\"/, "\"\"", name)
                gsub(/\"\"/, "\"", name)
                gsub(/\"/, "\\&quot;", name)

                gsub(/,/, "", hands)

                label = 8;

                if ((hands >= 100) && ((vpip / 1.40) <= (100 / avgp))) {label = 7}  #Tight
                if ((hands >= 18) && ((vpip / 1.00) <= (100 / avgp))) {label = 7}   #Tight
                if ((hands >= 100) && ((vpip / 1.25) <= (100 / avgp))) {label = 6}  #Nit
                if ((hands >= 24) && ((vpip / 2.20) >= (100 / avgp))) {label = 5}   #Semi-Loose
                if ((hands >= 15) && ((vpip / 3.00) >= (100 / avgp))) {label = 4}   #Loose
                if ((hands >= 30) && ((vpip / 2.60) >= (100 / avgp))) {label = 4}   #Loose

                if ((hands >= 24) && ((vpip / 2.60) >= (100 / avgp)) && ((pfr/vpip) <= 0.2)) {label = 3}    #Fish

                if (name in fishes)     {label = 3} #Fish
                if (name in bluffers)   {label = 2} #Bluffer
                if (name in goodregs)   {label = 1} #GoodReg
                if (name in badregs)    {label = 0} #BadReg
            }
```

After this point, when I finally got the proper label type for a player, I'd like to do a search in the *.xml file, if the player can be found, then I'd like to update his label number, if he is not found, I'd like to print a line beside to the other players into the *.xml file like this:

```
printf("\t<note player=\"%s\" label=\"%s\" update=\"%s\"></note>\n", name, label, update)
```

Then save the *.xml file and do this again line by line when processing the csv file. In the first case, if the player can be found, it's important to not to replace the whole line in the *.xml file, just update the label, because some players can also have some notes included (like in the example code) which would get lost if we replace the whole line. So the real question is, can these replacements done in the first place? If they can I'd appreciate it if someone would shed me some light about where should I continue:) Of course if there's a better way to this instead of save and search line by line, I'm interested to hear about it.

Comment: must It be done with awk? I think is better with [xsl transformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp)

Comment: Is it hard to learn to use it? How would it do the job in theory? If it's not too hard I'm interested.

Comment: if your `awk` script doesn't fit on a page you're using a wrong tool for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr update.txr 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
        <label id="0" color="80FF80">BadReg</label>
        <label id="1" color="FFFF40">GoodReg</label>
        <label id="2" color="8000FF">Bluffer</label>
        <label id="3" color="10FF10">Fish</label>
        <label id="4" color="1080FF">Loose</label>
        <label id="5" color="30DBFF">Semi-Loose</label>
        <label id="6" color="0000FF">Nit</label>
        <label id="7" color="FF9F48">Tight</label>
        <label id="8" color="C0C0C0">Undefined</label>
    </labels>
    <note player="00aquitis00" label="7" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="01 LUGAR" label="8" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="07 Star 07" label="4" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="109185" label="7" update="1429834930">Some notes are here</note>
    <note player="1111167" label="8" update="1429834930">And some there...</note>
    <note player="&quot;Seikei&quot;&amp;5RS" label="0" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="#23Mattingly" label="5" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="#PachnacyBak" label="2" update="1429834930"></note>
    <note player="eagle189" label="6" update="1429834930"></note>
</notes>
```

Code in `update.txr`:

```
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@;; Lisp struct and globals ;;
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@(do
   ;; Structure representing a player
   (defstruct player ()
     name label (update g-update) notes
     (vpip 0.0) (pfr 0.0) (hands 0) (avg 0.0)

     ;; post-construction hook
     (:postinit (self)
       ;; calculate label based on stats, if possible
       self.(calc-label)
       ;; If a player exists by the name, copy the properties to the old one
       ;; otherwise add the new one to the global list.
       (iflet ((old [name2player self.name]))
         old.(update-from self)
         self.(add))))

   ;; Add new player method
   (defmeth player add (self)
     (push self allplayers)
     (set [name2player self.name] self)
     (set g-update self.update))

   ;; Merge new player with existing entry
   (defmeth player update-from (old new)
     (set old.label (or new.label old.label))
     (set old.vpip (or new.vpip old.vpip))
     (set old.pfr (or new.pfr old.pfr))
     (set old.hands (or new.hands old.hands))
     (set old.avg (or new.avg old.avg)))

   ;; Method to calculate player's numeric label value.
   (defmeth player calc-label (p)
     (if (> p.avg 0.0)
       (let ((ravg (/ 100 p.avg)))
         (when (and (>= p.hands 100) (<= (/ p.vpip 1.40) ravg))
           (set p.label 7))
         (when (and (>= p.hands 18) (<= (/ p.vpip 1.00) ravg))
           (set p.label 7))
         (when (and (>= p.hands 100) (<= (/ p.vpip 1.25) ravg))
           (set p.label 6))
         (when (and (>= p.hands 24) (>= (/ p.vpip 2.20) ravg))
           (set p.label 5))
         (when (and (>= p.hands 15) (>= (/ p.vpip 3.00) ravg))
           (set p.label 4))
         (when (and (>= p.hands 30) (>= (/ p.vpip 2.60) ravg))
           (set p.label 4))

         (when (and (>= p.hands 24) (>= (/ p.vpip 2.60) ravg)
                    (> p.vpip 0.0) (<= (/ p.pfr p.vpip) 0.2))
           (set p.label 3)))))

   ;; Convert a player to XML.
   (defmeth player toxml (p)
      `<note player="@{p.name :filter :tohtml}" \
      \ label="@{p.label}" update="@{p.update}">@{p.notes}</note>`)

   ;; Global list of all player objects
   (defvarl allplayers nil)

   ;; Hash mapping player names to player objects.
   (defvarl name2player (hash :equal-based))

   ;; Global variable storing most recent player update value.
   (defvarl g-update)

   ;; Hash of lower-cased label type strings to ID strings.
   (defvarl type2label (hash :equal-based)))
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@;; Process Notes.xml file               ;;
@;; - instantiates player objects        ;;
@;; - snarfs labels as labelxml list      ;;
@;; - populates type2label hash          ;;
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@(next "Notes.xml")
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
@(collect :gap 0 :vars (labelxml))
@  (all)
@    labelxml
@  (and)
        <label id="@id" color="@co">@na</label>
@  (end)
@  (do (set [type2label (downcase-str na)] id))
@(end)
    </labels>
@(repeat :gap 0)
    <note player="@na" label="@l" update="@up">@nt</note>
@  (do (new player name na label l update up notes nt))
@(end)
</notes>
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@;; Process ReportExport.csv file          ;;
@;; - just instantiates specified players  ;;
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@(next "ReportExport.csv")
"","Player","VPIP","PFR","Hands","Players"
@(repeat :gap 0)
"@junk","@na","@vpip","@pfr","@hands","@avg"
@  (do (new player
            name (regsub #/""/ "\"" na)   ;; handle "" -> " in name (CSV)
            vpip (tofloat vpip)
            pfr (tofloat pfr)
            hands (toint (remql #\, hands)) ;; nuke comma digit separator
            avg (tofloat avg)))
@(end)
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@;; Process players.txt                    ;;
@;; - look up layer in name2player hash    ;;
@;; - look up label in type2label hash     ;;
@;; - if we have both, set player's label  ;;
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@(next "players.txt")
@(repeat)
@name @type
@  (do (let* ((pl [name2player name])
              (id [type2label (downcase-str type)]))
         (when (and pl id)
           (set pl.label id))))
@(end)
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@;; Output updated XML                     ;;
@;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
@(bind playerxml @(mapcar (umeth toxml) (nreverse allplayers)))
@(output)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
@  (repeat)
@       labelxml
@  (end)
    </labels>
@  (repeat)
    @playerxml
@  (end)
</notes>
@(end)
```

Diff between original `Notes.xml` and output. Here we can see that user `109185` was updated, because that user has been added to the CSV.

```
$ diff -u Notes.xml <(txr update.txr)
--- Notes.xml   2015-12-21 16:04:51.790042327 -0800
+++ /dev/fd/63  2015-12-22 09:06:49.075320182 -0800
@@ -14,6 +14,10 @@
     <note player="00aquitis00" label="7" update="1429834930"></note>
     <note player="01 LUGAR" label="8" update="1429834930"></note>
     <note player="07 Star 07" label="4" update="1429834930"></note>
-    <note player="109185" label="6" update="1429834930">Some notes are here</note>
+    <note player="109185" label="7" update="1429834930">Some notes are here</note>
     <note player="1111167" label="8" update="1429834930">And some there...</note>
+    <note player="&quot;Seikei&quot;&amp;5RS" label="0" update="1429834930"></note>
+    <note player="#23Mattingly" label="5" update="1429834930"></note>
+    <note player="#PachnacyBak" label="2" update="1429834930"></note>
+    <note player="eagle189" label="6" update="1429834930"></note>
 </notes>
```

Contents of `player.txt`. Note that these users are given their correct labels in the output, overriding the labels calculated from their stats.

```
#PachnacyBak    bluffer
"Seikei"&5RS    badreg
```

Contents of `ReportExport.csv`:

```
"","Player","VPIP","PFR","Hands","Players"
"2532|100|""Seikei""&5RS","""Seikei""&5RS","20.45","12.50","88","5.65"
"4265|100|#23Mattingly","#23Mattingly","41.94","25.81","33","5.55"
"2748|100|#PachnacyBak","#PachnacyBak","11.54","10.00","52","5.44"
"6|100|eagle189","eagle189","20.60","13.60","73,561","5.55"
"blah","109185","15.60","8.60","20","4.55"
```